# How to push bootstrap bottom popover to the left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to push the popover which is coming down a little bit to the left side. Then Arrow would stay on the right top corner of popover.

I tried this

```
 $('#popper').on('shown.bs.popover', function(){
      $('.popover').css('left','774px');
 });
```

but not working - if i resize window, the popover stays where it was, not following where it came up. how can i achieve this?

original state:

[image]

what i want is:

[image]

Comment: can you post the relevant code or a fiddle?

Comment: @TilwinJoy, well this is the code, rest of it is just a library of bootstrap